# ->result() not showing all data/rows

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a question

Let say we have this 2 tables in our database

first table : category_lists

[image]

second table: data_category

[image]

so **if list_data_id is equal to 1** meaning that it has **2 data** if you look at **data_category table** which is **6** and **7**

Now what I want is to query from **category_list table** so that **6** and **7** will echo **Car Wreckers** and **Cash For Cars**.

This is what my code looks like:

below is my controller:

```
 public function index($listing_name)
{
    $this->load->view('layouts/head_layout_seo');
    $this->load->view('layouts/head_layout');

    $data['main_view'] = 'listings/main_view';
    $data['listing_data'] = $this->Listing_model->get_detail_listing($listing_name);

    $list_id = $data['listing_data']->list_data_id; // this is what I get list_data_id is equal to 1

    $data['category_ads'] = $this->Ads_model->get_ads($list_id); // this is what you need to look

    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

    $this->load->view('layouts/footer_layout');

}
```

below is my model:

```
  public function get_ads($list_id)
{
    $this->db->where('list_data_id', $list_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('data_category');
    $query = $query->result();
    //return $query;
    if (count($query) > 0) {    
        for ($i=0; $i < count($query); $i++) { 
            foreach ($query as $value) {
                $this->db->where('category_lists_id', $value->category_lists_id);
                $querys = $this->db->get('category_lists');
                //print_r($query);
                return $querys->result();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

below is my view:

```
 foreach ($category_ads as $value) {
<p><a href=""><?php echo $value->categories; ?></a></p>  }
```

with the code above I get only **1 data** which is **Car Wreckers** as you can see from the table, it supposes to show **2 data** **Car Wreckers** and **Cash For Cars**

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank You

Comment: I'm not familiar with Codeigniter but by looking at your logic, your foreach loop only goes through the first element after that you return the value, it never reaches to the end of the array.

Comment: Also you have a nest loop, which will print the result multiple time if there are more than 1 results in the `data_category` table.

Comment: why don't you use `join` in a model query?

Comment: $query = $query->result_array();

Comment: @catcon if I place the line return $querys->result(); after the closing bracket of foreach loop I will get the Cash For Cars instead not Car Wreckers.

Comment: @MohitKumar I tried that it does not help, only show 1 result

Comment: @M.Hemant can you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in your model so no need to call `DB` two times and no need to `loop`

```
public function get_ads($list_id)
{
   $this->db->select('cl.category_lists_id,cl.categories');
   $this->db->from('category_lists cl');
   $this->db->join('data_category dc','cl.category_lists_id = dc.category_lists_id');
   $this->db->where('dc.list_data_id',$list_id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows() > 0){
       return $query->result();
   }else{
       return array();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, I've been looking for this answer the past 2 days